# How to make a button selected by default in JToolbar

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jtoolbar

I created a small tool set which is composed of around 10 buttons. These buttons are added to a `JToolBar`. Currently, it puts a square around the first button by default; however, I would like a different button to be the default. How can I accomplish this? Below is an example of how I am adding the buttons. I have tried `select.setSelected` and a few other methods but haven't had any luck.

```
  JToolBar sideBar = new JToolBar();

  JButton select = new JButton(new ImageIcon("Media/select.png"));
  select.setBorderPainted(false);
  select.setContentAreaFilled(false);

  sideBar.add(select);
```

Here's an image of the current result:

[image: current result - notice square on top left button]

Comment: In the future, a print screen would be useful so we understand what the "square" you are seeing is (which in this case, I presume, is the "focus" square that Swing assigns)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know which button you want to be active, you can use

```
button.requestFocusInWindow();
```

You can also try to set the default button at the root pane, depending on the set up of your Swing elements.

```
rootPane.setDefaultButton(button);
```

And finally, there is a handy method called `setFocusedPainted(false);`

Comment: I tried this but I don't see any difference. The blue focus square is still staying around the first button.

Comment: -1, don't use requestFocus() (see the API for this method), use requestFocusInWindow().

Comment: Sorry, I meant to put that!

Comment: button.requestFocusInWindow(); did the trick, thank you very much everyone

Answer (score 2):

You may want to set one button as the default button for the toolbar this way:

```
yourToolBar.getRootPane().setDefaultButton(okButton);
```

I often use the `setDefaultButton` method within Dialog boxes so the user can select the default button by pressing [Enter].

Comment: Thanks Thorn, this will be useful for the dialog boxes I have.